# Spark specify ssh port for worker nodes

Tags: apache-spark, ssh

I'm trying to set up a local Spark cluster. When I add the IP addresses of the workers to `spark/conf/workers` it tries to ssh into them on the default port 22 when I run `sbin/start-all.sh`. I have my ssh ports set differently for security reasons. Is there an option I can use to configure spark to use alternate ports for ssh from master to workers, etc?

Answer (score 2):

You should add the following option for `/path/to/spark/conf/spark-env.sh`

```
# Change 2222 to whatever port you're using
SPARK_SSH_OPTS="-p 2222"
```